# Angular huge bundle size due to angular and firebase modules

Tags: angular, webpack, bundle, angularfire

I'm new to Angular development and I'm currently looking into how to optimize Angular's bundle sizes. I've read a lot of posts about the bundle analyzer, imports, modules, lazy loading etc.

My application is fairly small but does still load a vendor bundle with 2MB (11MB uncompressed):
[image]

I've already put the larger part (where a big 3rd party lib is used) into a lazy loaded module, but this saved only a few KB.

The biggest modules seem to be:

- angular
- firebase
- material
- moment

Is it possible to reduce size for these modules?
I do not see any places where I import more than needed. Some parts are not even from me.

Comment: Too many questions in one post. How to reduce / use only one locale for moment should be its own question (after researching and attempts).

Comment: You're right! I've edited my question and will open up a new one for the moment issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good practice to reduce the final build of an Angular application is to use Angular's Ahead-of-Time (AOT) compiler. Here's some details from the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler):

> Smaller Angular framework download size. There's no need to download the Angular compiler if the app is already compiled. The compiler is roughly half of Angular itself, so omitting it dramatically reduces the application payload.

It is also interesting to integrate Webpack in your compilation, specially for production builds. [Here's a link to a blog post](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-configure-webpack-4-with-angular-7-a-complete-guide-9a23c879f471/) describing the integration process of Angular 7 and Webpack 4.

Comment: The prod version of the angular build is using the aot option by default. I've just generated the stats for the non-prod version (I've read to do it like this in some blog posts), therefore the compiler etc was included. Thanks, this explains this!